# Automatically change margins when printed

Tags: pdftex, pdf, margins, printing

I'm burned out writing my thesis and as it usually happens I spent a long time messing with the formatting. For electronic submission, we have to use:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}  
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
```

which is fine for on-the-screen reading. But, when I went to review the printed copy, the margins are terrible if printed double sided. So, for printing, I change it to:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright]{report}  
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, twoside]{geometry}
```

and it looks great on paper (but can't be used for electronic submission -- and it looks bad when reading on a screen).

Since build times are over 8 minutes each time I compile it, I would like to avoid having to maintain two builds. Is there a package or trick (probably a PDF command/option) that would let it behave like the first set of options (ie. left margin always 1.5in) on the screen, but when I hit print it will behave like the second set of options?

I'm using `pdflatex` as the engine, because the university templates refuse to compile with anything else.

Comment: I'm afraid not, unless you set the different PDF boxes (e.g. Trim, Crop and Bleed) and convince your viewer or your printer to use one of these. But that's definitely non-standard. Just generate two pdfs, one for the screen and a different one for printing.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I suspected there would not be a way to do it and I would have to keep making two PDFs. I was hopeful there was some awesome hack out there to make it work though.